# Javascript Closures – Returning Object to Calling Function

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, angularjs

I am using Cordova and Angular for a small webapp. Here is the implementation process:

1. `LogsModel` is created
2. `queryLogs()` is called
3. `getLogsArray()` is called – at this point, even in the function definition, `console.log(this.logs['0'])` returns `undefined`. I do not understand why.

---

```
LogsModel.prototype.logs = {};

LogsModel.prototype.getLogsArray = function (){
    console.log(this.logs['0']);
    return this.logs;
};

LogsModel.prototype.queryLogs = function (){

    var self = this;

    function getFromDb (tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO',[],querySuccess,self.query_fail);
    }

    function querySuccess(tx,results){
        var len = results.rows.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){

            var log = {
                verb: results.rows.item(i).verb
            };
            self.logs[i]= {
                verb: results.rows.item(i).verb
            };
        }
    }
    this.db = window.openDatabase("Database","1.0","Cordova Demo",200000);
    this.db.transaction(getFromDb,self.transaction_fail);
};
```

Comment: Why are you writing to the array with an integer key but reading with a string key? (`this.logs['0']` vs just `this.logs[0]`)

Comment: That is a remnant of my troubleshooting.

Comment: @johusman: It won't make a difference. In JS, all properties are converted to string.

Comment: Yes, but it is confusing and asking could potentially have revealed a larger problem :)

Comment: Solution: Passed a callback function in the scope of the controller (where `queryLogs` is invoked) that accepts a data parameter. I invoke the callback, which returns the data to my controller, and all is well (enough). In a very round-about, trial and error process I used Bergi's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`queryLogs` is an asynchronous task. Call `getLogsArray` directly after starting the transaction and the array won't be populated yet.

Instead, use a callback which you invoke from the `querySuccess` function to continue processing (e.g. logging results).

Comment: OK, it helps to identify the type of task it is – now I know why the method returns empty. At this point, I still do not understand how I would have a callback in `querySuccess` that could provide the result back to where `queryLogs` is initially invoked from. Thoughts?

Comment: No, it never can. You would need to use [cps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). If you want to return something useful from the function, have a look at Deferred objects